# Strange differences in tf.keras model construction in versions 1.4 and 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I have noticed differences in net topology building in tf.keras in 1.4 and 2.0 versions. I'd like to build net with sharing layers like that:

```
    digit_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(27, 27, 1))
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(digit_input)
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    out = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

    vision_model = keras.models.Model(digit_input, out)

    # Then define the tell-digits-apart model
    digit_a = keras.layers.Input(shape=(27, 27, 1))
    digit_b = keras.layers.Input(shape=(27, 27, 1))

    # The vision model will be shared, weights and all
    out_a = vision_model(digit_a)
    out_b = vision_model(digit_b)

    concatenated = keras.layers.concatenate([out_a, out_b])
    out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)

    model = keras.models.Model([digit_a, digit_b], out)
```

And if you check connections between layers (i'm interested in input layers) then you'll get smth like that:

```
tf2

input_2 --> []
input_3 --> []
input_1 --> []
conv2d --> ['input_1', 'input_2', 'input_3']
conv2d_1 --> ['conv2d', 'conv2d', 'conv2d']
max_pooling2d --> ['conv2d_1', 'conv2d_1', 'conv2d_1']
flatten --> ['max_pooling2d', 'max_pooling2d', 'max_pooling2d']
concatenate --> ['model', 'model']
dense --> ['concatenate']



tf1

input_2 --> []
input_3 --> []
input_1 --> []
conv2d --> ['input_1']
conv2d_1 --> ['conv2d']
max_pooling2d --> ['conv2d_1']
flatten --> ['max_pooling2d']
concatenate --> ['model', 'model']
dense --> ['concatenate']
```

The question: Is it a bug or a feature, cause I use this stuff for keras models convertion in custom framework format. And i would like to maintain tf2 compatability.

There is a code for printing connections:

```
from tensorflow import keras


def toList(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    return [x]


def printInputLayers(layer):
    inputLayers = []
    for node in toList(layer._inbound_nodes):
        for inbLayer in toList(node.inbound_layers):
            inputLayers.append(inbLayer.name)
    print(layer.name + " --> " + str(inputLayers))


def printModelsInputLayersForEachLayer(model):
    for layer in model.layers:
        if not isinstance(layer, keras.models.Model):
            printInputLayers(layer)
        else:
            printModelsInputLayersForEachLayer(layer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = keras.models.Model(...)
    printModelsInputLayersForEachLayer(model)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can it be because of new feature `eager execution`?